# What reasons would the government need ghosts?

Tags: ghosts

I am writing a story about ghosts. The government summoned these ghosts for a specific task(s). What might these tasks be? The ghost I'm working on is a ten-year-old girl in a small town who makes a friend with another girl (living).

Rules of the ghosts

- The ghosts can touch physical objects if they want, but they need a small amount of focus.
- They can turn invisible.
- They can only appear as the age they died or younger.
- They can take as much time to do the tasks unless stated by the person who gave the task.
- They are not necessarily evil; they have free will.
- They cannot go back until they complete the task.
- They have the choice to go back once they complete the task.

If you have any questions, please ask. I will answer it.

Comment: Can  you make clear why this is not about your story but rather about the rules of your world? I miss that point

Comment: [Why would someone X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6338/40609) questions are off-topic because you're not asking about a rule of your world (worldbuilding) but rather character actions/choices (storybuilding). [How do I justify/explain X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7376/40609) questions are on-topic because they're asking about the world's rules (e.g., "how can ghosts exist in my world?" possible answer: "magic," which is a system or rule of the world). (\*continued\*)

Comment: Is this really a character choice question? If so, leave a message in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) and when I get back from work I'll happily throw some suggestions at you. You can ask anything in chat.

Comment: Ok, I did that.

Comment: Can ghosts of dead people (technically) vote in election?

Comment: I don't know. I never thought about that. But yeah, I guess they could.

Comment: can the ghost kill life people or [kill another ghost to death](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/001/593/peopledie.jpg)?

Comment: Yes, they can kill living people, as they can hold guns and knives. They cannot kill other ghosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Intelligence

Ghosts can become invisible and they can go through walls, so they can spy on people much more effectively than social media. They can then report organized crime and dissidents to the authorities.

This is even more effective if the ghosts can be summoned up with their effects. Deceased photographerd with ghost cameras would be the bane of criminals in a free society, or the bane of dissidents in an authoritarian society.